# How to construct a filename with a table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table **c{}** that stores some image file names in a folder named data,
and i want to use `res = image.load(filename)` to load them iteratively.

But it seems like `res = image.load('./data/'..c[i])`  didn't work. (Assume that c[i] stores a name *'3.jpg'*.)

So how can i use a table to construct a filename? In what form?

Comment: The string concatenation seem fine. `image.load` is not a standard Lua function. Perhaps it returns an error message or code telling your what went wrong?

Comment: Probably, the current directory is not what you are expecting it to be.  Try filename with full path.

Comment: `image.load` is a function in a third party library of Torch. But the parameter `filename` is a standard string value. And I've tried full path but it didn't work too. So I think probably the syntax is wrong.

Comment: What is the error message?  Are file permissions ok?

Comment: I 've solved this problem by directly reading a text with file names by lines. I think probably the problem is that the datatype **table** stores objects and you cannot use an object to be as a string `filename` parameter.@EgorSkriptunoff